# How do I access tabs in an Excel workbook once saved?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook-pro

I have an associate who sent me an Excel file with tabs at the bottom to switch to different worksheets within the doc.  When I save the document, I can't see/don't know how to open the different tabs to work on the different worksheets.  I see them when I click on "quick look" in my email, but when I save it as an Excel doc and open in Excel, I can't find the tabs.

Comment: looks like you're saving it as CSV instead of Excel

Answer (score 1):

Go to “Excel Options”, “Advanced”, “Display options for this workbook”, and ensure that “Show sheet tabs” is checked:

[image: Excel Options]

Alternatively, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to navigate between worksheets.